# Recursive extraction of object values and parent key name using jq

Tags: json, npm, jq

I have a requirement to parse the output of the `npm ls --global --json` command, such that I get a list of all the installed `npm` packages in the following format:

`$package;$version;js;$resolved`

Where:

- `$package` is the key containing the package name, from each `dependencies` object.
- `$version` is the `version` value taken from each package
- `js` is just a literal string
- `$resolved` is the `resolved` value taken from each package

I have gotten as far as this command syntax and output:

```
$ jq --raw-output 'select( has("dependencies") ) .dependencies[] | . as $d | "parentkey" + ";" + $d.version + ";js;" + $d.resolved'`
parentkey;5.5.1;js;
parentkey;1.1.3;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/yaml-table/-/yaml-table-1.1.3.tgz
```

The parts that I am specificly having difficulty with are as follows:

- How can I get the key name value that I am iterating over in `.dependencies` that contains that package name. It seems that by that point I am looking at the contents of that object itself.
- How can I recurse through ALL dependency objects? At the moment I'm only looking at the top level records in the root `.dependencies` object. I've discovered `..` recursion, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it here.

Based on the example data below, I am trying to reach the following output results:

```
npm;5.5.1;js;
JSONStream;1.3.1;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream/-/JSONStream-1.3.1.tgz
jsonparse;1.3.1;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse/-/jsonparse-1.3.1.tgz
through;2.3.8;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/through/-/through-2.3.8.tgz
yaml-table;1.1.3;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/yaml-table/-/yaml-table-1.1.3.tgz
js-yaml;3.4.6;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.4.6.tgz
argparse;1.0.9;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse/-/argparse-1.0.9.tgz
```

Some (much reduced) sample output `npm ls --global --json` that I have used for the above example, is as follows:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": {
      "version": "5.5.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "JSONStream": {
          "version": "1.3.1",
          "from": "JSONStream@~1.3.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream/-/JSONStream-1.3.1.tgz",
          "dependencies": {
            "jsonparse": {
              "version": "1.3.1",
              "from": "jsonparse@^1.2.0",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse/-/jsonparse-1.3.1.tgz"
            },
            "through": {
              "version": "2.3.8",
              "from": "through@>=2.2.7 <3",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/through/-/through-2.3.8.tgz"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "yaml-table": {
      "version": "1.1.3",
      "from": "yaml-table@latest",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/yaml-table/-/yaml-table-1.1.3.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "js-yaml": {
          "version": "3.4.6",
          "from": "js-yaml@3.4.6",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.4.6.tgz",
          "dependencies": {
            "argparse": {
              "version": "1.0.9",
              "from": "argparse@>=1.0.2 <2.0.0",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse/-/argparse-1.0.9.tgz"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `..`, it will recurse through all values in the json tree. So you'll want to filter those out by objects that have the structure you're expecting. In this case, things that have a valid `dependencies` object. Once you've located the objects, you could extract the values you want.

```
jq -r '.. | .dependencies? | objects
    | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.version, "js", .value.resolved] | join(";")' input.json
```

produces the results:

```
npm;5.5.1;js;
yaml-table;1.1.3;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/yaml-table/-/yaml-table-1.1.3.tgz
JSONStream;1.3.1;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream/-/JSONStream-1.3.1.tgz
jsonparse;1.3.1;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse/-/jsonparse-1.3.1.tgz
through;2.3.8;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/through/-/through-2.3.8.tgz
js-yaml;3.4.6;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.4.6.tgz
argparse;1.0.9;js;https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse/-/argparse-1.0.9.tgz
```

Comment: Wonderful. Many thanks. I'll go read up on those particular things in the docs now so I get a better understanding of them.