# How to use jq to extract variable keys and their values from JSON?

Tags: json, jq

If I have a JSON file with variable key names like this:

```
{   
    "john": {"age": 40, "nickname": "jo"},
    "mary": {"age": 50, "nickname": "mo"}
}
```

How do I use `jq` to extract the keys with some of their values?

Example: Extract the names and their ages:

```
"john": 40
"mary": 50
```

Comment: Try this: to_entries[] | {(.key): .value.age}

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll write it as answer, so you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the particular case you mention, the following filter could be used:

```
to_entries[] | "\"\(.key)\": \(.value.age)"
```

Using the -r command-line option (e.g. jq -rf program.jq) with your input produces:

```
"john": 40
"mary": 50
```

See also:

[Recursive extraction of object values and parent key name using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629417/recursive-extraction-of-object-values-and-parent-key-name-using-jq)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
to_entries[] | {(.key): .value.age}
```

Output:

```
{
  "john": 40
}
{
  "mary": 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the object to an array of key/value pairs first; then you can iterate over that and access the key and associated value in tandem.

```
$ jq 'to_entries' tmp.json
[
  {
    "key": "john",
    "value": {
      "age": 40,
      "nickname": "jo"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "mary",
    "value": {
      "age": 50,
      "nickname": "mo"
    }
  }
]
$ jq 'to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value.age)"' tmp.json
"john: 40"
"mary: 50"
```