# iterating json to store key value pairs using shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, jenkins, hashicorp-vault

I have a json file that is getting created at runtime using the sh script within groovy code. The json file has below contents.

cat.json

```
{
    "user1":"pass1",
    "user2":"pass2",
    "user3":"pass3"
}
```

Now I want to create a file at runtime which stores key value pairs in below format

test

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
user3:pass3
```

can some one help me out shell codes for writing this.

Comment: In Jenkins using groovy you can use: `def content = readJSON(file: 'PATH').collect{"$it.key:$it.value"}.join('\n');   writeFile file: 'NEW_PATH', text: content`

Answer (score 0):

You have literally dozen ways to convert that JSON document to a tabular data file (pretty much like CSV/colon-SV) since you mentioned Java, Groovy, including Java-driven scripting engines (BeanShell, JavaScript, Groovy itself), but if you can use `jq` then you can extract k/v pairs at least for simple values that do not require any escaping:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value)"' \
    < cat.json
```

This answer is inspired by searching for extracting entries using `jq` (or converting a JSON file to a CSV file) and especially by the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496145/12232870 by [@peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak).

Comment: Thanks @fluffy. the script works in my local system but while executing it in jenkins groovy it gives a syntax error  WorkflowScript: 41: unexpected char: '\' @ line 5 column 3.
          jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value)"'